# visual studio multiple project . how to use one variable of one project into another

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-c#-express-2010, multiple-projects

I have two projects and i need to combine them into one solution. 
How do i map a variable from one project to another project?? 
My one project is developed in visual c++ 2010 and another project is developed in visual c# 2010. 
1.I have to use variable of c++ project into c# project.
2. I also want to know how do i switch control of final solution from one project to another means how do i launch one project from another?

```
face_cascade.detectMultiScale( grayscaleFrame, faces, 1.1, 3,
                               CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE,
                               Size(30,30));

if(faces.size()==1)
{
   cout<<faces.size();
}
for(int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
{
   Point pt1(faces[i].x + faces[i].width, faces[i].y + faces[i].height);
   Point pt2(faces[i].x, faces[i].y);
   rectangle(captureFrame, pt1, pt2, cvScalar(0, 255, 0, 0), 1, 8, 0);
   a=pt1.x;
   b=pt1.y;
}
```

I have to map a and b to another project. 
Thank you for your help!!

Comment: There is not enough information here to make a suggestion. Is one of the projects an exe and the other a DLL? If they are both exes then you will have to look into interprocess communication or shared memory.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'Project'?  A .cs File? An .Exe?